# Index of highest index in NSMutableIndexSet

Tags: objective-c, ios, set, indexing, nsindexset

How can I get the index of the highest (numerical) index contained in an `NSMutableIndexSet`?

I.e the position in which the highest NSUInteger (index) is in the `NSMutableIndexSet`?

```
NSArray *results = [subCategory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if([results count] == 1) {

    returns = [results objectAtIndex:0];

 }

else if ([results count] > 1) {

     NSMutableIndexSet *set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

     for (NSString *subCat in results) {

        NSUInteger indexs = 0;

        for (NSString *comp in components) {

            if ([subCat rangeOfString:comp].location != NSNotFound) {

                indexs ++;

            }

        }

        [set addIndex:indexs];

    }


    // find the position of the highest amount of matches in the index set

    NSUInteger highestIndex = ...;

    returns = [results objectAtIndex:highestIndex];   

}
```

Comment: Actually, given your code, isn't the highest index always going to be added last? My answer below helps for a more general case.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have 5 minutes before I can accept your answer, it works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track as you add values to the index set:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *set = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSUInteger maxIndexs = 0;
NSUInteger indexOfMax = NSNotFound;
for (NSString *subCat in results) {
    NSUInteger indexs = 0;
    for (NSString *comp in components) {
        if ([subCat rangeOfString:comp].location != NSNotFound) {
            indexs ++;
        }
    }

    if (indexes > maxIndexs) {
        maxIndexs = indexs;
        indexOfMax = set.count;
    }
    [set addIndex:indexs];
}

// find the position of the highest amount of matches in the index set
NSUInteger highestIndex = indexOfMax;

returns = [results objectAtIndex:highestIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableIndexSet` is a subclass of `NSIndexSet`.  `NSIndexSet` understands the [`lastIndex` selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002197-BAJDDCAC):

> Returns either the last index in the index set or the not-found indicator.

Comment: Hi Rob, I understand that the question could be quite ambiguos. I want to receive the index of the largest number in that set.

Comment: The largest number in an `NSIndexSet` is the `lastIndex` of the set.  Perhaps what you are actually trying to do is figure out which element of `components` occurs most often (as a substring) in `results`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Or are you trying to figure out which element of `results` contains the most elements of `components` as substrings?

Comment: The latter, I'm looking for which element of results contains the most elements of components as substrings.